# Is there a way to save the content of both my EditText to a users phone to be retrieved later?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a note app that sets the content of  both edit text to the user's phone.The title text will be used for the display of the the image button title which the user will click on to access the content of that file.Thank you!

````
    private EditText title, activity;
    private Button saveBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_entry);

        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        activity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Activty);
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        title.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        String str = title.getText().toString();```

}
}
````

Answer (score 1):

You can easily store data using SharedPreferences or SQLite. [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) is a good tutorial same like your note app, you can follow this. But the latest approach is Using Room Database. For room, you can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)